# chrome extension ajax call onstartup

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension

Here's what I'm trying to achieve with my Chrome extension and the issue I'm facing:

- My extension runs an ajax call every x minutes to a server and based on the result, displays the updated information in the extension pop-up window.
- I was able to implement all of this logic with my ajax call made from popup.js and it works perfectly fine.
- The only limitation I currently face is that the extension user has to click on the extension icon for the popup.js/html script to be triggered and executed (which is expected).

**- I'm  trying to figure how to trigger the ajax call function when the browser is launched.**

**Solution trial 1:** I moved my ajax call and response logic from popup.js to background.js and included a chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener. The problem with this approach is that background.js can't access my popup DOM and thus I cannot display my updated information.

**Solution trial 2:** I kept my ajax call and response logic in popup.js. In background.js, I added a chrome.runtime.sendMessage within the chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener. The problem with this approach is that popup.js is not triggered obviously (no user click on extension icon yet) and thus apparently not able to get the message from background.js to execute the ajax call.

I'm pretty confused with what is the right approach to follow, it feels a bit like an chicken & egg problem.

Any help or feedback would be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

P.S: I'm using Manifest V3

Comment: Solution 1 + [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm for the reply. Provided I go with Solution 1 + messaging, I face 2 other challenges: 1. Getting jquery library to be recognized in my background.js file. I have tried different approaches in my manifest but so far its not working. 2. How my popup.js would be able to receive the message from background.js since its only executed when the extension icon is clicked.

Comment: 1) You don't need jquery in background script and it won't work in the background script because there's no DOM in ManifestV3. 2) The popup runs only when shown so it'll receive a message only when it runs, sounds straightforward to me, I don't see why it's a problem.

Comment: 1) I am currently making a ManifestV3 extension so I understand I have the following options: Either switch to a manifest V2 extension 2. or replace Jquery ajax call with a native XMLHttpRequest call in background.js 2) so are you saying onstartup = 1 ajax call (to update the extension icon) and then whenever the user clicks on the pop-up 1 ajax call to get the latest info?

Comment: You'll use `fetch`, not XHR, but yes you're right. Additionally you can store the info in chrome.storage.local so the popup will read it first, then send a message to the background script so it fetches the new info.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll give it a try.